# Tomcat not showing full stack trace in Error Report for Http status 500 error

Tags: apache, tomcat, safari

Tomcat not showing full stack trace in Error Report for Http status 500 error in some client. And it is showing stacktraces when I tried from different client(Machine).

My question is,

Is there any setting in Browser/Apache Config to get full stacktraces in error report?

Comment: All the logs in the server by default go to logs/catalina.out. Have you checked there?