# Show stacktrace on 500 error when calling tomcat via REST

Tags: rest, tomcat, logging, error-handling

How can I configure tomcat to show the actual stacktrace during a 500 error on a REST call? Currently I only get a "System error occurred - 500" type of message. Is there a plugin/configuration setting that will allow me to add more detail in the returned error?

I see a similar question: [Tomcat not showing full stack trace in Error Report for Http status 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416096/tomcat-not-showing-full-stack-trace-in-error-report-for-http-status-500-error)  but this suggests going to the server logs. I would like (at least in development mode) to see the error at the client side.